# Cozyroc MailTask script not working

Tags: ssis

I am trying to use CozyRoc's script to perform mail server tasks like moving emails from one mail folder to another. I am using the script found here:

[CozyRoc Mailtask Script](https://www.cozyroc.com/script/mail-task)

So far it doesn't work. The error i get is that my connection manager is not found, which makes no sense. In a different package I have set up a fetch mail attachments process with success, so my connection is tested and working. Anyone used it before with success?

Comment: Are these difference package files? Do you have the connection manager from the fetch mail attachments package defined in the package that is using the MailTask Script? Can you show us the exact error you're getting?

Comment: @digital.aaron i have no idea what was going wrong. Creating a new project from scratch with the exact same setup solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a new project from scratch with the exact same setup i used in the previous one solved the problem. I was unable to figure out why, but this solved the problem.